# javax/mail/MessagingException in jar file but same code working in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I am creating a sample project to send a mail. When i am trying to send a mail using eclipse it works fine. But as soon as i make a .jar file of the code it created the jar file but when i run the code using "**java -jar test.jar**" it shows me

```
"**Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException**"

Complete Error Description:
** 
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.yourcabs.MailThread.run(MailThread.java:27)
```

I am having my jar file structure like this
    **/META-INF**
    **/org**
    **/javaee-api-6.0.jar**
    **/mail.jar**

I tried google and it didn't work for me. Also i tried cleaning and rebuilding the project also that not worked.

Can any one help me on this. Am i missing something.

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ javaee-api-6.0.jar mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar mail.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: org.yourcabs.SMSMessenger
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader

Comment: Please see this post can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499090/need-assistance-setting-up-a-class-to-send-email-it-gets-called-from-the-main-c

Comment: As per answer from above post you need to have java mail API jar separately in your classpath when you are trying to run it from outside.

Comment: @HarishKumar I tried doing the same but that also not worked for me. Is there any specific way of doing that. I was trying to edit in Manifest file.

Comment: can you try using following from command line:  java -cp <your mail.jar>;<your jar file> <class file to execute with package name in your jar file>. Hoipe you are on windows system.

Comment: Please post your file manifest.

Comment: @HarishKumar

i ran the following command "java -cp test.jar /home/prateek/Downloads/javamail-1.4.7/mail.jar org.yourcabs.SMSMessenger" and it has given me error "Error: Could not find or load main class .home.prateek.Downloads.javamail-1.4.7.mail.jar" all the paths and the class name and package name are correct

Comment: i updated the same in question please check

Comment: Please use: java -cp test.jar;/home/prateek/Downloads/javamail-1.4.7/mail.jar org.yourcabs.SMSMessenger   You missed ';'

Comment: @HarishKumar i tried the same but it gave me the error "**invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error**"

Comment: So you are on Linux it seems. Please replace ';' between jar files with ':' if that is the case

Comment: yeah thanks it worked. But my question is if the mail.jar are present in the jar i am running then why it is not taking that up. Why i have to add the external jar url

Comment: Can you also please accept the solution. I have copied it in answer section too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is caused by a different version of your mail.jar. Be sure you are using the same jar from eclipse and from your command-line. Eclipse could use a built-in mail.jar or an instance server's mail.jar.

Comment: i am using same version of mail.jar.

When i am exporting and making a jar from eclipse it is bundled along with the jar file

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are several versions of your javax/mail/MessagingException .
Look for that class in both your mail.jar and javaee-api-6.0.jar .

Answer (score 0):

You are on Linux it seems. Please replace ';' between jar files with ':' if that is the case

What is Rsrc-Class-Path? I think Manifest should look like:

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Class-Path: ./ javaee-api-6.0.jar mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar mail.jar

Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader

You need to adjust class path as required.

Comment: What is Rsrc-Class-Path? I think Manifest should look like:Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: ./ javaee-api-6.0.jar mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar mail.jar
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader

Comment: the solution you have mentioned earlier has helped. I tried modifying Manifest file but it didn't worked.

Comment: Give classpath in manifest as: Class-Path:  /META-INF/org/javaee-api-6.0.jar/mail.jar <rest of jar with their respective location in jar file you want to execute> and use java -jar test.jar. See if it solves your issue.